# XHR access to github's participation info

Tags: javascript, github, xmlhttprequest

I am writing a simple widget that renders a canvas participation graph just like the one's on github.

It uses the data at http://github.com/[user]/[repo]/graphs/participation

The widget works great and is basically done. The only problem I have is when I try to retrieve the json data from the above link via XHR (rather than just copying and pasting into the widget as I have been), I run into the same origin access control problem.

Is there any way I can access this information at all, either via XHR or some hidden github api feature?

Comment: You cannot get around this client-side. You will need to create a proxy server-side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Github supports JSONP and [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) through its [API](http://developer.github.com/v3/).  You could also setup a server-side proxy, through which XHR requests are made to a same-origin page which then does a server-side request to Github.

---

To answer your question about the proxy, yes it's very simple.  I had actually done this exact thing about two years ago using Python and Tornado.  I realize this isn't PHP, but it reads close enough to english to give you the idea about how it works.  This particular proxy was returning a raw gist.

```
# /proxy/gist
class GetGistHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self, id, filename):
        url = 'http://gist.github.com/raw/%s/%s' % (id, urllib.quote(filename))
        resp = urlfetch.fetch(url)
        self.finish(resp.content)
```

It can then be consumed with something along the lines of

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/proxy/gist',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: {
        id: $('#id').val(),
        filename: $('#filename').val()
    },
    success: function(json) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: So for the proxy deal, I would just create, say, a simple php script that when hit with an XHR GET, would interpret some extra parameters I add specifying the targeted github page, do the request, then spit back the results?